# Can I take an old LEGO winch apart?

Tags: piece-information, cleaning, disassembly

I have an old LEGO winch that looks like [#73037](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=73037)

[image]

It has been "restrung" but it is very stiff and it looks like it has some of the old string stuck between the rotating and non-rotating parts. It also feels a bit gritty so there might be dirt stuck in there.

It looks like the top on each side might come off and if so I would be able to remove the stuck string and clean it.

Does anyone have any advice about taking it apart without damaging it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just can't. This part is fused together with sound-waves so it doesn't separate anymore.

Source and more info: [fusing Lego together](http://forums.reprap.org/read.php?1,36904)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The winch may be too old to have been fused by this process but I can't know for sure. Nevertheless, I'm not going to try and open it!